# React Material UI Box not wrapping text on Firefox

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, firefox, material-ui

This is my code:

```
TableCellComponent={memo(({ sortDirection: _, ...componentProps }) => (
                    <Box
                        {...componentProps}
                        display="flex"
                        flex={1}
                        alignItems="center"
                        px={2}
                        py={1.75}
                    />
                ))}
```

This is the result on Chrome:
[image]

This is the result on Firefox:
[image]

Any ideas how to fix this?

I tried adding `min-width: 0;` to the `sx` prop of , as suggested under a similar issue but it didn't work. I tried also `overflow-wrap: break-word;` but that property doesn't seem to be available on the `sx` prop.